# jQuery - how do I assign events on more than one variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 or more variables which were selected with jQuery, and I want to assign click events on all of them with the same function. Or one variable and one selector. How do I do it? I could do:

```
function click_event_1(var_1, var_2) {
    var_1.on("click", function() {
        alert(1);
    });
    var_2.on("click", function() {
        alert(1);
    });
}

function click_event_2(var_1, selector) {
    var_1.on("click", function() {
        alert(1);
    });
    jQuery(selector).on("click", function() {
        alert(1);
    });
}
```

But I want to write only one function for each event.

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/add/. Also, nothing prevents from declaring he function once and pass it to each call of `.click`. You don't *have to* use a function expression when binding event handlers.

Comment: "But I want to write only one function for each event." - Why?  Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hi @Uri, You can use ```CLASS``` of the elements with which you want to bind events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least) two choices:

1. Use a named function:

   ```
   function click_event_1(var_1, var_2) {
       var_1.on("click", handler);
       var_2.on("click", handler);

       function handler() {
           alert(1);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/), which creates a new jQuery set with the union of the set you call it on and the set you give as an argument:

   ```
   function click_event_1(var_1, var_2) {
       var_1.add(var_2).on("click", function() {
           alert(1);
       });
   }
   ```

Both will also work with your second example (`add` accepts a selector as well as a set).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) which will add to the jQuery collection, whether it is an element, or a selector:

```
var_1.add(var_2).click
```

Or:

```
var_1.add(selector).click
```

The event will apply to all elements in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class for those elements.

```
var element1 = $('#element1');
element1.addClass('clickable');
var element2 = $('#element2');
element2.addClass('clickable');

// for elements inside an iframe
var iframeElement1 = $('#iframeElement1', $('iframe').contents());
iframeElement1.addClass('clickable');

// you can add more elements here

$('.clickable').on('click', function (event) {
   // do click logic here
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but one element may be inside an `<iframe>` and can not be selected directly.

Comment: Use $('#iframeElement1', $('iframe').contents())